# Media Players in Radio Buttons play on top of each other instead of playing one at a time

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to get these songs set up as Radio Buttons to play one at a time, instead they play on top of each other and when there done they don't play again once clicked.

I have a single Radio Group with 18 Radio Buttons for each track, I don't know what Java code to put inside of each case in the switch statement to make a song stop when another is clicked and also re-play again once re-clicked. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.adiodopeheadz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.os.Build;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener,    
     OnClickListener {

MediaPlayer track1, track2, track3, track4, track5, track6, track7, track8, 
track9, track10, track11, track12, track13, track14, track15, track16, track17,   
   track18;




Button Team;
Button Shows;
Button Contact;

RadioGroup tracks;



     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {



    Team = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Contact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    track1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track1);
    track2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track2);
    track3 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track3);
    track4 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track4);
    track5 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track5);
    track6 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track6);
    track7 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track7);
    track8 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track8);
    track9 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track9);
    track10 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track10);
    track11 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track11);
    track12 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track12);
    track13 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track13);
    track14 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track14);
    track15 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track15);
    track16 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track16); 
    track17 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track17);
    track18 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.track18);


    tracks = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);


    tracks.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);




    }


   }


    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
     }


@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
    switch(arg1){
    case R.id.track1:

        break;

    case R.id.track2:

        break;

    case R.id.track3:

        break;

    case R.id.track4:

        break;

    case R.id.track5:

        break;

    case R.id.track6:

        break;

    case R.id.track7:

        break;

    case R.id.track8:

        break;

    case R.id.track9:

        break;

    case R.id.track10:

        break;

    case R.id.track11:

        break;

    case R.id.track12:

        break;

    case R.id.track13:

        break;

    case R.id.track14:

        break;

    case R.id.track15:

        break;

    case R.id.track16:

        break;

    case R.id.track17:

        break;

    case R.id.track18:

        break;

    }
    }


@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}





 }
```

Comment: No one knows a solution for this???